# Change status bar color when screen pinned

Tags: android, android-statusbar, android-screen-pinning

I could change the **status bar** color by using following code when screen is **not pinned** .

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
       <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accentColor</item>
       <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/secondary_pody_part_color</item>
</style>
```

When i tried the same after **pinning** the screen via **startLockTask()** the statusbar color not getting changed. How to fix?

Comment: what is `startLockTask()`?

Comment: @SohailZahid startLockTask() is a function that Request to put this Activity in a mode where the user is locked to the current task. See this. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startLockTask()

Comment: maybe fix it in java code?

Comment: @Genehme I have also tried that. But there was no effect when screen is pinned.

Answer (score 0):

Change it dynamically before `startLockTask()` :

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE); //Or any other
```